# SwiftUI Animation.fluidSpring() replacement

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swiftui

I'm using Xcode Beta 7, and following a tutorial where they use `Animation.fluidSpring()`. I couldn't find a `.fluidSpring()` anywhere in the autocomplete. Did they replace it? If so, what is the replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [macOS 10.15 Beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_catalina_10_15_beta_8_release_notes):

> > > Updated the APIs for creating animations. The basic animations are now named after the curve type — such as `linear` and `easeInOut`. The interpolation-based `spring(mass:stiffness:damping:initialVelocity:)` animation is now `interpolatingSpring(mass:stiffness:damping:initialVelocity:)` , and `fluidSpring(stiffness:dampingFraction:blendDuration:timestep:idleThreshold:)` is now `spring(response:dampingFraction:blendDuration:)` or `interactiveSpring(response:dampingFraction:blendDuration:)` , depending on whether or not the animation is driven interactively. (50280375)

So either `spring` or `interactiveSpring`.